# What causes "no tables in statement" message?

Tags: c, sqlite, libdbi

I'm following [this](http://libdbi.sourceforge.net/docs/programmers-guide/quickstart-code.html) example program, but I'll be using SQLite3 instead of MySQL.

At first I need to check the `user_version` to see if the tables are created and up to date.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbi/dbi.h>

#define CONF_PATH "./"
#define DB_FILE "db.sqlite3"

int main() {
    dbi_conn conn;
    dbi_result result;
    dbi_inst instance;

    long ver = 0;

    dbi_initialize_r(NULL, &instance);
    conn = dbi_conn_new_r("sqlite3", instance);

    dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "sqlite3_dbdir", CONF_PATH);
    dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "dbname", DB_FILE);
    dbi_conn_set_option(conn, "encoding", "UTF-8");

    if (dbi_conn_connect(conn) < 0) {
        printf("Could not connect. Please check the option settings\n");
    } else {
        result = dbi_conn_query(conn, "PRAGMA user_version;");

        if (result) {
            if (dbi_result_next_row(result)) {
                ver = strtol(dbi_result_get_string(result, "user_version"), NULL, 10);
            }
            dbi_result_free(result);
        }

        printf("DB Ver. %ld\n", ver);

        dbi_conn_close(conn);
    }

    dbi_shutdown_r(instance);

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works as it should, but I get a strange output:

```
no tables in statement !
DB Ver. 1
```

The second line is OK. I print it on line 33 of my code. How about the first one? It is obvious that there's no tables in statement, but I don't print and don't want this message...

My systems is:

Debian sid

gcc (Debian 4.8.2-14) 4.8.2

libdbi1 0.9.0-1

libdbd-sqlite3 0.9.0-2

I build the program using `gcc -ldbi -ldl -std=c11 -Wall -Werror dbtest.c -o dbtest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [message printed by libdbi sqlite3 driver](http://sourceforge.net/p/libdbi-drivers/libdbi-drivers/ci/master/tree/drivers/sqlite3/dbd_sqlite3.c#l1197) [`find_result_field_types()`](http://sourceforge.net/p/libdbi-drivers/libdbi-drivers/ci/master/tree/drivers/sqlite3/dbd_sqlite3.c#l812) that attempts to deduce the field types from the query string.

Since it's open source, you can fork the code and remove the message you don't want. There's  a [bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/libdbi-drivers/bugs/), too.

Comment: So this should be a bug. As I can see the other `printf`s are commented. I'll see what can I do about this. Thank you!